# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm creating a search bar for a project model with Laravel, Inertia.js, and Vue.js.

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return Inertia::render('Projects/Index', [
        'projects' => Project::where('project_name', 'LIKE', '%' . 
            $request->search . '%')
            ->paginate(7)
    ]);
}
```

**Index.vue template**

```
<input id="search" type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Search..." 
    v-model="search" @keyup="searchProject">
```

**Script**

```
data(){
      return {
          search: ''
      }
  },

methods: {
      searchProject: _.throttle(function(){
          this.$inertia.get("/projects", { search: this.search }, 
          { preserveState: true });
      },200)
  }
```

Whenever I type anything on the search input, nothing renders, and I get the following error in the console.

[image: Error in Console]

I've read that this may be caused by my vue version, in package.json I have:

```
@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
"vue": "^3.0.5",
```

Comment: I think it has to do with how you render those results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just fixed this. For anyone out there experiencing this issue or something similar. Here's a possible solution. When the search result is empty, the DOM is trying to render a Null object. So, wrap everything inside a:

```
<div v-if="projects.data">
  Your Logic here
</div>

<div v-else>
     Empty Prop
</div>
```

Comment: So it's not quiet clear what you did to fix this.  Also do you happen to have a small project to show the error.  I'm running into a similar issue but on a big project and would like to see a bug submitted to Vuejs

Comment: Could also be the VueJS version, at the time I was working on this project, I was using Vue 2, The same code from the Original question worked just fine on Vue 3, but not sure tho.

Comment: I'm on Vue3 and have found there is some internal issue with using v-if.  When I've ran into it I've had to change to a v-show in some situations